not able to get Web push notification in safari in iOS device
I am trying to send Web Push notification in angular and have used service worker for the notification.
In Chrome it is working overall Fine on iOS device.
but in Safari not able to get web push notification in iOS device and i have latest software version in iOS which is 17.5.1,
but still not able to get notification in iOS device
async subscribeToPush() {
    try {
      let sw = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
      let sub = await sw.pushManager.subscribe({
        userVisibleOnly: true,
        applicationServerKey: "PUBLIC_VAPID_KEY"
      })
      console.info(sub);
      const { publicKey, privateKey } = await this.generateKeyPair();
      this.publicKey = publicKey;
      this.privateKey = privateKey;
      const exportedPublicKey: any = await exportPublicKey(this.publicKey);

      const exportedPrivateKey: any = await exportPrivateKey(this.privateKey);
      let SubscriptionDataDto = {
        subscriptionDto: sub,
        publicKeyBase64: exportedPublicKey,
        publicKeyId: null,
      }
      this.notificationService.subscribe(SubscriptionDataDto).subscribe(response => {
        try {
          if (response) {
            this.subscriptionData = JSON.stringify(response);
            this.localService.saveData(STORAGE_KEYS.PUBLIC_KEY, exportedPublicKey)
            this.localService.saveData(STORAGE_KEYS.PRIVATE_KEY, exportedPrivateKey)
            this.localService.saveData(SOTRAGE_DATA.SUBSCRIPTION_DATA, this.subscriptionData)
            this.router.navigate([ROUTES.TICKET]);
            this.counter = this.counter + 1;
            this.decryptService.sendData(this.counter);
            this.decryptService.sendData(this.counter);
            this.toastr.success(this.translate.instant("toastrMsg.notificationSuccess"));
          } else {
            this.toastr.error(this.translate.instant("toastrMsg.notificaitonError"));
          }
        } catch (error) {
          this.toastr.error(this.translate.instant("toastrMsg.notificaitonError"));
        }
      });

      async function exportPublicKey(key: CryptoKey) {
        const exported = await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey("spki", key);
        return btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(exported)));
      }

      async function exportPrivateKey(key: CryptoKey) {
        const exported = await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey("pkcs8", key);
        return btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(exported)));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  async generateKeyPair() {
    const keyPair = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
      {
        name: KEYS.RSA_OAEP,
        modulusLength: 2048,
        publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
        hash: { name: KEYS.SHA_256 },
      },
      true,
      ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
    );

    return keyPair;
  }


https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending-web-push-notifications-in-web-apps-and-browsers
